# SQL criteria table with mul

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I'm trying to apply security permissions and determining which HR employees should have access to which employees in the company.

My criteria table has at least 8 different fields that can be utilized for access (eg region, division, business unit, head of department, etc) with associated values.

I've simplified it with the two images that give a high level view of the data and criteria.  Any help on how I can end up with the desired result in the third image?

Thanks!

**CRITERIA TABLE**

[image: CRITERIA TABLE]

**DATA**

[image: DATA]

**DESIRED RESULT**

[image: DESIRED RESULT]

Comment: Do not use images for textual information per here [Images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). There is already one close vote for this.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Pivot the criteria, so that it can be joined to the data.

```
SELECT 
  c.USER
, d."Emp ID"
, c.region
, c.div
, c.mgnr
FROM DATA AS d
JOIN
(
    SELECT t.USER
    , MAX(CASE WHEN t.column = 'region' THEN t.Value END) AS region
    , MAX(CASE WHEN t.column = 'div' THEN t.Value END) AS div
    , MAX(CASE WHEN t.column = 'mgnr' THEN t.Value END) AS mgnr
    FROM CRITERIA t
    GROUP BY t.USER
) AS c
  ON c.region = d.region 
 AND c.div = d.div
 AND c.mgnr = d.mgnr
ORDER BY d."Emp ID"
```